# How to extract values from single database column / store in array

Tags: php

I am hoping someone can help me with this. I am trying to extract all the values from a single column of a database and store the returned values in a numeric array.

```
$num = 1;
 $q = "SELECT `uninum` FROM `participants` WHERE `islecturer` = '".$num."'";
    $result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q);
    $storeArray = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        $storeArray [] =  $row['uninum'];  
    }


    echo $storeArray [1];
```

Comment: So whats not working? For a start you can remove the error suppression from the query `@` is almost never a good idea

Comment: Oh okay, thanks Steve. At present I have not got it to work at all. I am getting an error message for this line $storeArray [] =  $row['uninum'];for 'Undefined index' for 'uninum'

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'` around the column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to `mysqli_fetch_array` sets the array type. You have set it to a numerical index. You want an associative index:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { //correct flag
    $storeArray [] =  $row['uninum'];  
}
```

Or just use the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` function instead:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $storeArray [] =  $row['uninum'];  
}
```

Comment: @Ray No problem, glad i could help